# Comparing two directories and build difference directory of changed or new files

Tags: windows, gratis, comparison, directories

Are there any gratis Windows tools that can compare two folders as `source` and `destination` in deep and export the differences with folder structure.

So considering below sample

```
Source
  > File 1
  > File 2
  + Branch
    - File 3
    - File 4


Destination
  > File 1 (changed)
  > File 2 (same)
  + Branch
    - File 3 (changed)
```

I am looking for a tool that can build below structure 
`compare Source Destination Diff`

```
Diff
  > File 1
  + Branch
    -File 3
    -File 4
```

I am using Windows (10) and looking for some free or open source software. Something like *Winmerge* but with the ability to create the difference as a complete directory structure.

Comment: Did you have a look at robocopy or checked if Beyond Compares export functionality can do what you need ?

Comment: Taking your output example, would it be OK to show _File 1_ at the bottom of the structure? If that's the case, you could use WinMerge (`View` -> `Show Identical Items` unchecked; `View` -> `Show Different Items` and `Show Binary Files` checked; `View` -> `Tree Mode` checked, `Expand All Subfolders`). Let me know and I'll add a full answer.

Comment: @mguassa will winmerge create a `destination` folder and copy the changed and new files to that `destination` folder?!

Comment: @Marged beyond compare is not free. But I will check `robocopy`  in details (as a quick look it  does not have this option)